# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{r =1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2r-1) 4^{r-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the sum of the series

$$\sum_{r =1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2r-1) 4^{r-1}}$$

Since the denominator form an odd sequence

I am trying to use the series expansion like

$$x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} + \cdots =  \frac{1}{2} \log\left(\frac{1 +x}{1-x}\right)$$

to simplify the given series, but haven't achieved any success.

Can anyone give some hint  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint...write $4^{r-1}$ as a power of $2$

Comment: Thank you!, it was so easy  just required a bit  of observation.

Comment: You're welcome...